# Google Analytics for WPF C# Desktop Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Do we have any official **google analytics SDK to integrate into the WPF app**? I have gone through many articles but none of them provide the usage of the integration.

Also, Can we integrate **google analytics 4 into the WPF app**? Any SDK is available?

Kindly help here.

Comment: There's a UA google analytics SDK for WPF?  where's that? Link please.    What does this SDK do, is it sending data to google analytics or are you requesting data from google analyitcs?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I want to know can we integrate google analytics in WPF app? Please share some link describing the steps to integrate.

Comment: What do you want to integrate exactly?   Do you want to send hits to google analytics?   or do you just want to request data from google analytics.   You can do either or both.

Comment: I need to track page views, events of my WPF application. Need to send it to the google analytics.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Can you please let me know what all things will be sent to the google analytics server by default on sending any event using HTTP Post request?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Also how can I track page views? Do I need to manually send some event or it will automatically get tracked? If not automatically then what parameters do I need to send in HTTP Post request for tracking page/screens of desktop app?

Comment: GA4 doesn't have page views its all events.  You should probably review the measurement protocol documentation.  Its very limited what you can send currently, Thats why i stopped working on my .net SDK i am waiting for them to open up for it.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Thanks for the clarification.
Can't we integrate Firebase or gtag.js with WPF desktop app?

Comment: Sorry I cant answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the measurement protocol for ga4 its just http Post requests

```
POST /mp/collect HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.google-analytics.com
Content-Type: application/json
<payload_data>
```

[measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4)

There is no official SDK, I have been working on my own version but I have been waiting for them to complete the protocol